# Remove traversed portion of an android google-maps polyline

Tags: android, google-maps, google-polyline

I want to remove the portion of a drawn polyline as it was traversed, sort of like a `GPS`. I am currently getting location updates via: `onLocationChanged` from `LocationListener` interface.

I draw my polylines from a google-directions request. It behaves like a `GPS` right now in the way that if you deviate from the road it will make another request to draw the correct polyline:

```
if (!PolyUtil.isLocationOnPath(mLatLng,polylines.get(index).polyline.getPoints(), true, 20)) {
    //remove it
    //add a new polyline
}
```

I managed to redraw the polyline by making a direction request on each location change. This however is not a suitable way to do it because it will generate way too many request.

Is there any way to remove a certain portion of a polyline?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes: you can get points of polyline, remove point and set points to polyline back:

```
List<LatLng> polylinePoints = polylines.get(index).polyline.getPoints();
polylinePoints.remove([INDEX_OF_POINT_TO_REMOVE_1]);
polylinePoints.remove([INDEX_OF_POINT_TO_REMOVE_2]);
...
polylines.get(index).polyline.setPoints(polylinePoints);
```